# Jasmine does not instantiate an object of a constructor, in spite of using exports to make the function global

Tags: function, jasmine, prototype

I have a function which is local to one js file, but exports is used to make it global. When I am trying to instantiate it in a  spec, jasmine threw an error saying that the function is not defined.

RoomReservation Function:

```
RoomReservation = (function() {
RoomReservation.prototype.searchRatePlans = function(search, callback, filter) {
....
        };

return RoomReservation;
  })();
exports.RoomReservation = RoomReservation;
```

Jasmine Spec:

```
it('To test RoomReservation function',function(){
                    var filter='groupCode';
                    var search='g';
                    spyOn(RoomReservation.prototype, 'searchRatePlans'); 
                    var k = new RoomReservation();
                    expect(k.searchRatePlans).toHaveBeenCalled();
                });
```